# Getting Undefined index error and Method name must be a string in ..error in PHP

Tags: php, php-7

While upgrading to PHP7, I encountered these problem.

The issue is am trying to create codes that I can reuse like a mini-framework and the RUN function where the problem is used to load the relevant template and supplying the variables. It complains about

> undefined index

of these 2 variables

```
$controller = $routes[$this->route][$this->method]['controller'];
$action = $routes[$this->route][$this->method]['action'];
```

and it also complained about this line

```
$page = $controller->$action();
```

which displayed

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Method name must be a string in...

```
public function run() {

            $routes = $this->routes->getRoutes();   

            $authentication = $this->routes->getAuthentication();

            if (isset($routes[$this->route]['login']) && !$authentication->isLoggedIn()) {
                header('location: /login/error');
            }
            else if (isset($routes[$this->route]['permissions']) && !$this->routes->checkPermission($routes[$this->route]['permissions'])) {
                header('location: /login/permissionserror');    
            }
            else {
                            $controller = $routes[$this->route][$this->method]['controller'];
                            $action = $routes[$this->route][$this->method]['action']; 
                            $page = $controller->$action();
                $title = $page['title'];

                if (isset($page['variables'])) {
                    $output = $this->loadTemplate($page['template'], $page['variables']);
                }
                else {
                    $output = $this->loadTemplate($page['template']);
                }

                echo $this->loadTemplate('layout.html.php', ['loggedIn' => $authentication->isLoggedIn(),
                                                             'output' => $output,
                                                             'title' => $title
                                                            ]);

            }
```

This is the index.php

```
try {
    include __DIR__ . '/../includes/autoload.php';

    $route = ltrim(strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?'), '/');

    $entryPoint = new \Ninja\EntryPoint($route, $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], new \Ijdb\IjdbRoutes());
    $entryPoint->run();
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    $title = 'An error has occurred';

    $output = 'Database error: ' . $e->getMessage() . ' in ' .
    $e->getFile() . ':' . $e->getLine();

    include  __DIR__ . '/../templates/layout.html.php';
}
```

The code is much, so, I can't display the whole code here since am using MVC pattern, but if there is anything you still want to know, I will gladly post it here

Comment: the obvious question is what is the value of these 3 variables `$routes`, `$this->route` and `$this->method`  do `var_dump` on them and it should become obvious.  Then check that they exist in `$routes`, it's just guessing without that info.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix it dumped all the classes in the project specific directory and also all classes in project generic directory.

Comment: After var_dumping $routes...this displayed all the classes in the project specific directory and also all classes in project generic directory

Comment: while $this->routes displayed <<string(12) "public/index">>

Comment: and $this->method displayed <<<string(3) "GET">>>

Comment: If you want a better way to output stuff you can use my `Debug` class you can find it on my [GitHub](https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Debug) page.  It has recursion protection (something `var_export` and friends lack), a depth limit setting (for nesting depth) you can output only  some stuff from an object like the constants, or protected properties (even the private properties) and if that wasn't enough it will also output the line and file number that the `debug::dump` method was called on (so you can find the debug calls after you no longer need them)  it outputs similar to `var_dump`

Comment: Oh and it's on composer under `evo/debug`, it even creates a set of function calls that wrap the class, so you can do the debug just by calling a function like `debug_dump($var)` instead of `Debug::getInstand()->dump($var)`  you have to set it up though (its all on the documented on Git), it's pretty sweet and I won't even charge you for it (it's free anyway ... lol)

Comment: how do you set`$routes[$this->route][$this->method]['controller']` , and `$routes[$this->route][$this->method]['action'];`  and create object of `$controller`

Comment: I suspect yer being caught out by this change in how variable expressions are parsed: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.indirect.

Comment: @veshraj Josh I never include it here for everything sake.  Also I have continually message Kevin yank to do the correction but all to no avail as he hasn't respond to it now

Comment: @adam Cameron.  I have tried it but still no effect maybe am doing it the wrong way

Comment: It's certain that your  `$routes[$this->route][$this->method]['controller'] `, and `$routes[$this->route][$this->method]['action'];` are not set. First try to findout why its not setting

Comment: can I give similar demo to get working

Comment: @VeshrajJoshi You can and it will highly appreciated if you can

Answer (score 3):

> This code is runnable in php 7.2.7 (MAMP and LAMP), your way of dynamic function calling is invalid and your two variables are empty. This is not exact as yours but you can take logic form this demo.

Ok i am just providing a very simple example of reflection with mapping url to class along with functions. I make folder structure like below- 
[image: folder structure of the image]

1. Here .htaccess is used to redirect all the url to index.php (if no file exists).
2. index.php include all code that could initialize code(for now only three files were there - uri.php, urlMapping.php and actions.php)
3. URI.php - have function that provide values like basepath, baseurl, uri
4. urlMappig.php - that allows you to provide which url hit which class along with method
5. actions.php will call dynamic class and function (reflection)

now look into code of index.php

```
    <?php
        include_once('URI.php');
        include_once('urlMapping.php');
        include_once('actions.php');

    ?>
```

aNow code insise uri.php file -

```
<?php
   // all function should be accessible to all file loaded now
   // return full url
    function full_url (){ 
        return (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    }
    // returns current directory
    function directory() {
        $parts = explode("/", __DIR__);
        return $parts[count($parts)-1];
    }
    // return base url
    function base_url(){ 
        $dir = directory();
        return  substr(full_url(), 0, strpos(full_url(), $dir)+strlen($dir));
    }
    // return uri
    function uri() { 
        return substr(full_url(), strlen(base_url())+1);
    }
?>
```

Now code in urlMapping.php

> Note - file name and name of the class must be same as you map url in
>   this file so that you can make call to dynamic classes and function on actions.php. If don't this will not work

```
<?php
    // this $urlMap will be accessed in actions.php
    $urlMap = [
        // here we use only uri so .. https://example.com/login hit LoginController class along with login function, this is just only the mapping
        'login' => ['class'=>'LoginController',
                    'function'=>'login'],
    ];
?>
```

Now actions.php code

```
<?php
    // if call is not like example.com/ means no uri is there
    if(uri()!='')
    {
        // if your uri exists in route collection or urlmapping collection then make call to your dynamic class and methods
        if(array_key_exists(uri(), $urlMap))
        {
            // include the class file dynamically from controllers folder
            include_once('controllers/'.$urlMap[uri()]['class'].'.php');
            // making references for dynamic class
            $controlerObject = new $urlMap[uri()]['class']();
            // call function dynaically from the referece
            $controlerObject->{$urlMap[uri()]['function']}();           

        }
        else
        {
            // you can make 404 page not
            echo 'No routing found';
        }
    }
    // call for home page 
    else
    {
        include_once('index.html.php');
    }
?>
```

Now controllres/LoginController.php class,

> Note - As mentioned above file name and name of the class as in urlMapping.php

```
<?php
    class LoginController{
        public function login()
        {
            // .... something your code goes here

            echo 'hello from the login function of login controller';
        }
        //...... other function you can define
    }
?>
```

Comment: could you please put your question in bounty ... providing much more points(over 100 points, you can have 200 or even 500 points ). If you think my answer is correct and helpful to you please accept after bounty.. Thanks

Comment: Am sorry because I don't know the meaning of bounty

Comment: Oh, its ok, no worries. Is this useful to you?

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `$page = $controller->$action();` check if `controller` and `action` are exists:

```
if (isset($routes[$this->route][$this->method]['controller']) 
    && isset($routes[$this->route][$this->method]['action'])) {
    $controller = $routes[$this->route][$this->method]['controller'];
    $action = $routes[$this->route][$this->method]['action'];
    $page = $controller->$action();
    // ...
} else {
   // return 404 Page not found
}
```

Comment: after putting all the codes inside the if(isset.....)) it does not display anthing